# write multiple dict to csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, csvwriter

I am trying to write below two separate dict values with the same key header to the csv file using python.

```
{'instrumentType': 'Stock Futures', 'expiryDate': '25-Jan-2023', 'optionType': '-', 'strikePrice': 0, 'identifier': 'FUTSTKTATASTEEL25-01-2023XX0.00', 'openPrice': 119.85, 'highPrice': 120.9, 'lowPrice': 118.3, 'closePrice': 119, 'prevClose': 119.8, 'lastPrice': 119.3, 'change': -0.5, 'pChange': -0.41736227045075125, 'numberOfContractsTraded': 13024, 'totalTurnover': 85557.26}
{'instrumentType': 'Stock Options', 'expiryDate': '25-Jan-2023', 'optionType': 'Call', 'strikePrice': 120, 'identifier': 'OPTSTKTATASTEEL25-01-2023CE120.00', 'openPrice': 4.1, 'highPrice': 4.7, 'lowPrice': 3.25, 'closePrice': 3.5, 'prevClose': 4.1, 'lastPrice': 3.55, 'change': -0.5499999999999998, 'pChange': -13.414634146341461, 'numberOfContractsTraded': 11663, 'totalTurnover': 2501.71}
```

I tried following the approach, but only one dict is getting stored in csv.

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ce_dt)
data.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Appreciate your help!!

**EDIT**

The data is stored in a variable as follows:

[image]

There is no comma **,** between the dict and that's why it is getting written only one dict.

Sample:

```
{'underlying': 'MARUTI', 'identifier': 'OPTSTKMARUTI25-01-2023CE8500.00', 'instrumentType': 'OPTSTK', 'instrument': 'Stock Options', 'contract': 'MARUTI 25-Jan-2023', 'expiryDate': '25-Jan-2023', 'optionType': 'Call', 'strikePrice': 8500, 'lastPrice': 143, 'change': 13.55, 'pChange': 10.47, 'volume': 1870200, 'totalTurnover': 306581886, 'value': 306581886, 'premiumTurnOver': 16203281886, 'underlyingValue': 8419, 'openInterest': 2798, 'noOfTrades': 18702, 'meta': {'symbol': 'MARUTI', 'companyName': 'Maruti Suzuki India Limited', 'industry': 'AUTOMOBILES - 4 WHEELERS', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'debtSeries': [], 'tempSuspendedSeries': ['IL'], 'isFNOSec': True, 'isCASec': False, 'isSLBSec': True, 'isDebtSec': False, 'isSuspended': False, 'isETFSec': False, 'isDelisted': False, 'isin': 'INE585B01010'}}
{'underlying': 'RELIANCE', 'identifier': 'OPTSTKRELIANCE25-01-2023CE2600.00', 'instrumentType': 'OPTSTK', 'instrument': 'Stock Options', 'contract': 'RELIANCE 25-Jan-2023', 'expiryDate': '25-Jan-2023', 'optionType': 'Call', 'strikePrice': 2600, 'lastPrice': 25.95, 'change': -14.3, 'pChange': -35.53, 'volume': 4438500, 'totalTurnover': 130269975, 'value': 130269975, 'premiumTurnOver': 11670369975, 'underlyingValue': 2516.65, 'openInterest': 15109, 'noOfTrades': 17754, 'meta': {'symbol': 'RELIANCE', 'companyName': 'Reliance Industries Limited', 'industry': 'REFINERIES', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'debtSeries': [], 'tempSuspendedSeries': [], 'isFNOSec': True, 'isCASec': False, 'isSLBSec': True, 'isDebtSec': False, 'isSuspended': False, 'isETFSec': False, 'isDelisted': False, 'isin': 'INE002A01018'}}
```

Comment: There is no comma , between the dict and that's why it is getting written only one dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to construct your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
dict2 = {"a": 3, "b": 4}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([dict1, dict2])
#    a  b
# 0  1  2
# 1  3  4

df.to_csv("out.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use standard `csv` module:

```py
import csv

lst = [dict1, dict2]  # lst is list of dictionaries

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=lst[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(lst)
```

Writes `data.csv`:

```
instrumentType,expiryDate,optionType,strikePrice,identifier,openPrice,highPrice,lowPrice,closePrice,prevClose,lastPrice,change,pChange,numberOfContractsTraded,totalTurnover
Stock Futures,25-Jan-2023,-,0,FUTSTKTATASTEEL25-01-2023XX0.00,119.85,120.9,118.3,119,119.8,119.3,-0.5,-0.41736227045075125,13024,85557.26
Stock Options,25-Jan-2023,Call,120,OPTSTKTATASTEEL25-01-2023CE120.00,4.1,4.7,3.25,3.5,4.1,3.55,-0.5499999999999998,-13.414634146341461,11663,2501.71
```

Comment: There is no comma , between the dict and that's why it is getting written only one dict.